# KDE5 shortcut for moving window to another workspace

Tags: kde5

How do I set a shortcut for moving a window to another virtual desktop (e.g. ctrl-alt-shift-[arrow] to drag it to an adjacant workspace), in KDE Plasma 5.x? I could not find this in the settings, and searching the web did not help either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Kubuntu 17.04 Zesty, in `System Settings > Shortcuts > Global Shortcuts > System Settings`, you have an option Window One Desktop [Down/to the Left/to the Right/Up]. Which is a slightly different place from what the other answer says.

Comment: thanks I kept searching for `move` and I couldn't find it

Comment: If you are looking for the shortcut to move the _screen itself_ to a different workspace, then search for "Switch One Desktop".

Answer (score 14):

In the `System Settings > Shortcuts > Global Keyboard Shortcuts > KWin`, you have an option `Window One Desktop [Down/to the Left/to the Right/Up]`, as well as some other options for moving windows to other desktops or screens.

(I found my solution by searching for `kwin move window desktop` and selecting time period `last year` and found [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260897/move-window-to-desktop-keyboard-shortcut/260898))

Edit: afterwards I also had a problem that the KWin option was not available from the dropdown. Restarting KWin fixed it: `kwin --replace`.

Comment: Please be aware that running `kwin --replace` and then closing the terminal window will make your desktop to stop working.

Comment: My global Shortcuts doesn't have a `KWin` component.